# Slim framework php installation giving error in index.php

Tags: php, slim

I am new to Slim PHP. I read documentation and installed `SLIM PHP` in my laptop. Here is how I have installed:

> 1. Installed composer
> 2. composer require slim/slim:"4.*"
> 3. composer require slim/psr7

I have followed these steps from http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/installation.html

And when I created `index.php` in root directory and pasted the `hello world` code, It's giving me errors in browser

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException: Not found. in E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\hadithsapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:93 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\hadithsapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(72): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\hadithsapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\hadithsapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(215): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\hadithsapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(199): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\hadithsapi\index.php(15): Slim\App->run() #5 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\hadithsapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php on line 93
```

Here is the `index.php` code:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Can you please tell me, why I am getting these errors. Please help me

Comment: How did you serve your application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your Slim Application from a sub-directory in your Server’s Root instead of creating a Virtual Host, you can configure the base path.

For example:

```php
$app->setBasePath('/my-sub-directory');
```

Read more

- [Run From a Sub-Directory](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html#run-from-a-sub-directory)
- [Slim 4 BasePath Tutorial](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html#base-path)
- [BasePath middleware](https://github.com/selective-php/basepath)
- [Running Slim 4 in a subdirectory](https://akrabat.com/running-slim-4-in-a-subdirectory/)